# How to install antlr4?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, antlr, antlr4

I read a lot in the antlr4 doc on github and I kind of understood how it works.
The thing is I am not a pro java coder, I am trying to use antlr4 with python.

Anyway I reached a deadend on the step to execute this

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Hello.g4
```

I downloaded the antlr4 complete.jar but I don't know how to setup or use it.
so any help?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @BrunoPeres Windows 8.1

Comment: You tried to follow [this instructions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#windows) in the ANTLR4's github page?

Comment: @BrunoPeres reached `SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Javalib\antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%` But failed on `java org.antlr.v4.Tool %*` and afterwards

Comment: @BrunoPeres `Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.v4.Tool`

Comment: What is exactly the name of your jar file?

Comment: @BrunoPeres `antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar` 
and I put it in the location `C:\Windows.old\Users\Michel Mina\AppData\Local\Temp\TMWDA8A.tmp\java\jre\win64\jre\lib`

Comment: Well, if your file is located into `C:\Windows.old\Users\Michel Mina\AppData\Local\Temp\TMWDA8A.tmp\java\jre\win64\jre\lib` and you are setting the classpath with `SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Javalib\antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%` this is the error. You need to try `SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Windows.old\Users\Michel Mina\AppData\Local\Temp\TMWDA8A.tmp\java\jre\win64\jre\lib\antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%`

Comment: @BrunoPeres Ahh yeah, I already changed the dir but still got the same problem 
I did now run these consequently and these are the outputs.
`C:\Users\Michel Mina>SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Windows.old\Users\Michel Mina\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\TMWDA8A.tmp\java\jre\win64\jre\lib\a??ntlr-4.5.3-complete.??jar;%CLASSP
ATH%

C:\Users\Michel Mina>java org.antlr.v4.Tool %*
Error: Could not find or load main class org.antlr.v4.Tool
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the -jar paramater easiest to use, so my command line (in a batch file) looks so:

```
set LOCATION=antlr4-4.5.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
java -jar %LOCATION% -Dlanguage=Cpp -listener -visitor -o generated/ -package antlrcpptest TLexer.g4 TParser.g4
```

taken from the [C++ ANTLR runtime demo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Cpp/demo/generate.cmd). You don't need to change your classpath, nor have to add any environment variables (or doskeys).

Answer (score 5):

**Don't Panic!!**

**This tutorial works for installing Antlr4 on a windows machine**

I know setting up the Antlr on a windows machine is a little bit complicated even tough some expert users think that it is not! However, I'm going to create a full tutorial and will try to cover "setting-up" and "testing" the Antlr on a windows computer **from  A-Z**.

It is assumed that you have installed [Java](https://java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml) you may check this from command line like picture below:

[image]

**Grab a cup of coffee or tea and follow the steps bellow:**

**1-** Go to http://www.antlr.org and download the Complete Antlr jar file like picture below

[image: Antlr download page]

**2-** Download Antlr.bat file: 
http://www.filedropper.com/antlr

To be able to call Antlr from the command line from any directory.

**3-** Download Grun.bat file from http://www.filedropper.com/grun
To be able to test the grammar and display various views of the parse tree.

**4-** Create a folder in **C drive** and name it **"Javalib"** and move all three files that you have downloaded to this folder, like picture below:
[image]

**5-** Open **Advanced system settings**

[image]

**6-** Open **Environment variables**

[image]

**7-** From **system variable**, edit **CLASSPATH** variable and simply add line below to the variable value `C:\Javalib\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar;` just like picture below:

[image]

**8-** Now find and edit **Path** variable, simply add `C:\Javalib;` to end of the line, like picture below:

[image]

**9-** Now let's test and see if it works! Simply write **antlr** in the command line, you should see something like this:

[image]

**Done!**

Hope this tutorial helps you, you're welcome to share your questions with me in the comment below :)

Comment: The bat files are not available anymore. Please attach or write it here, if you have that

Comment: @ShamsulArefinSajib you can manually create this bat file by this line... (java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*). I solved it using this and working fine

Comment: First file, antlr4.bat: java -cp antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool %* Second file, grun.bat: java -cp antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*

Comment: May need the path in the batch file.  First file, antlr4.bat: java -cp C:\Javalib\antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool %* Second file, grun.bat: java -cp C:\Javalib\antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*